# Changing application direction on the fly without restarting the whole application

Tags: android, react-native, internationalization

I'm developing a react native application in two languages, English and Persian(Farsi).
I'm using `I18nManager` for setting the application layout direction, but I manage translations by myself and I don't use `I18nManager` for translation. **so please note that my application translation is not related to the system locale.** and the application locale is completely independent from the system locale.

I pass application language as a prop to all children components in the hierarchy and manage their changes in `App.js` component (as the root component of system). (in App.js there is a state called `applicationLanguage`)

I have a function below that I am calling after setState for changing the `applicationLanguage`:

```
setApplicationDirection = (language: Language) => {
  I18nManager.allowRTL(language === Language.Farsi);
  I18nManager.forceRTL(language === Language.Farsi);
};
```

usage of `setApplicationDirection`:

```
onChangeLanguage = (language: Language) => {
  this.setState({
    applicationLanguage: language
  });
  this.setApplicationDirection(language);
};
```

after `onChangeLanguage` my translations has been changed without application restart. but application direction does not changed.

I know I can use `react-native-restart` and manually restart the application to take effect, but I would really prefer if changes would occur without restarting the application to provide a better UX. In my application the user can change the language in every screen and if I restart the application, he has to route to that screen again.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately